# Fop apache: two block fields into one line

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

The problem i'm having is displaying two block tags on one line:

```
<fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block color="#808080" font-size="30px" font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:text>Lot: </xsl:text>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="$test/lot"></xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

this shows up as:

> LOT:
>
> some_value

i want ti so show as:

> LOT: some_value

*edit:  < fo:inline >  doesn't work at all. throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fo:table-cell` contains only block-level FOs, so put them both in one `fo:block` that contains an `fo:inline` for 'Lot:':

```
<fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block>
        <fo:inline color="#808080" font-size="30px" font-weight="bold">Lot: </fo:inline>
        <xsl:value-of select="$test/lot" />
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: it worked! 

i still don't understand why it didn't, cause i tried with inline tags and never worked. well, now it works, and i've also successfully added inline to other parts of the code. nice, thanks :)

Comment: It would not have worked if you put the `fo:inline` (or text) as a child of `fo:table-cell`. The definition of every FO includes its allowed contents. For `fo:table-cell`, it's `(%block;)+` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_table-cell). You can get the expansion of `%block;`, etc., at https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e6532.